# In the Wolfram Cloud RotateLabel in ParmetricPlot does not rotate Y-Axis label

Tags: graphics

**Note this applies to version 10.3 running in the Cloud.**

```
ParametricPlot[{x,x},{x,0,1}, 
   Frame->True , 
   FrameLabel->{"X-Axis","Y-Axis"}, 
   RotateLabel->True]
```

The presence or absence of the option does make a difference to the positioning of the label but does not affect its rotation. It remains resolutely un-rotated in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't work in Desktop Mathematica either.

RotateLabel only takes a True or False. It doesn't take a list of them.

Comment: You're right but following that correction (question corrected) it still does not rotate the Y-axis label.

Comment: This seems to be local to Chrome.  In (an elderly version of) IE the labels are correctly rotated.

Answer (score 0):

`RotateLabel -> True` is the default behavior.

```
ParametricPlot[{x, x}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"X-Axis", "Y-Axis"}]
```

[image: RotateTrue]

`RotateLabel -> False`, on the other hand does influence the output:

```
ParametricPlot[{x, x}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"X-Axis", "Y-Axis"}, RotateLabel -> False]
```

[image: RotateFalse]